# Azure AD User assignment required for "multi-tenant wiht Personal accounts" application type

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have created an multi tenant with Personal account application type and set the "user assignment required" to yes on the service principal in the tenant

But this flag is ignored by Personal accounts during Login. Is this how it is supposed to work?

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer? Any other concerns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there seems not to be an official document about this question, "user assignment required" feature should only be available to the AAD tenant rather than personal Microsoft account.

We can only assign AAD users (including guest users) to the app. But we cannot do this for a personal account.

If there is a place where we can assign personal accounts to the app, it must be a tenant internally used by Microsoft to manage personal accounts. Obviously we have no access to that tenant(if it exists).

So now that we choose “multi-tenant with Personal accounts” application type, this Azure AD application should be available to any Personal accounts. They won't be restricted by "user assignment required" feature.